# How to Handle events using button in samsung smart TV?

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv

How to handle events while clicking button in samsung smart tv.if i design my form in scene means how i handle events please clear my doubt thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your index.html (main file) inside body tag define an a tag to make as 'anchor' for the key events:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="anchor" onkeydown="Main.keyDown();"></a>
```

Then in the Main.js file define the Main variable, a instance of TVKeyValue and Widget:

```
var widgetAPI = new Common.API.Widget();
var tvKey = new Common.API.TVKeyValue();

var Main =
{

};

Main.onLoad = function()
{
    // Enable key event processing
    this.enableKeys();
    widgetAPI.sendReadyEvent();
};

Main.onUnload = function()
{

};

Main.enableKeys = function()
{
    document.getElementById("anchor").focus();
};

Main.keyDown = function()
{
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;
    alert("Key pressed: " + keyCode);

    switch(keyCode)
    {
        case tvKey.KEY_RETURN:
        case tvKey.KEY_PANEL_RETURN:
        alert("RETURN");
        widgetAPI.sendReturnEvent();
            break;
        case tvKey.KEY_LEFT:
            alert("LEFT");
            break;
        case tvKey.KEY_RIGHT:
            alert("RIGHT");
            break;
        case tvKey.KEY_UP:
            alert("UP");
            break;
        case tvKey.KEY_DOWN:
            alert("DOWN");
            break;
        case tvKey.KEY_ENTER:
        case tvKey.KEY_PANEL_ENTER:
            alert("ENTER");
            break;
        default:
            alert("Unhandled key");
            break;
    }
};
```

For more information consult this Tutorial (in Spanish): http://samsungstad.com/wiki/iniciando-con-smart-tv/programando-tu-primera-aplicacion-javascript/